# regular expression for finding 'href' value that contains ".mp3" of a <a> link

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex pattern for finding mp3 links in HTML.

I tried `(<a href=")(\w*.mp3)(">)`, but I couldn't fetch `">` from that.

My strings are:

```
<a href="XXXXXX.mp3"></a>
<a href="1111111.mp3"></a>
<a href="123XXX.mp3"></a>
<a href="XXXX123.mp3"></a>
```

Comment: Please don't parse HTML with regexes.  Use an HTML parsing library, like AngleSharp.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/982149

Answer (score -1):

```
(<a href=")([^"']+\.mp3)(">)
```

So after some random searching, this seems to work.

Answer (score -1):

**try this:**

FIND: `<a[^>]+href="([^"]+\.mp3)"[^>]*>`